# Django Admin: change select box for foreign key to search autocomplete, like search objects

Tags: python, django, search, autocomplete, django-admin

The Django admin panel has a search autocomplete with `search_fields` on the list of objects of a model, but right now I have 3000 users. To add a user manually is dificult with the selectbox; I need the same behavior like the searchfields for selecting a user foreinkey `User`.

How can I include the Django search feature on the form for editing inside the admin panel?

```
from myapp.models import Red 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Red(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Cliente")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: Why can't you consider the `search_fields` added to ModelAdmin? I mean, if you create a ModelAdmin and consider adding the `customer` as a search_fields ?

Comment: search field im using but im need on edit form, like create or modify the object from django admin.

Answer (score 24):

Since Django 2.0, you can use [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) to generate autocomplete fields for foreign keys.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['username', 'email']

class RedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['customer']
```

Comment: is there a way to have different `search_fields` just for `autocomplete_fields` ? My search is on more fields than i would like to for autocomplete fields.

Answer (score 10):

Django has no built-in autocomplete functionality for foreign keys on admin but the [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) option may help:

```
class RedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("customer", )
```

If you want real autocomplete then you have to use 3rd-party app like [`django-autocomplete-light`](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) or some of the [other solutions](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete/).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Excellent idea with the raw_id_fields!

Comment: Good for performance!