# Custom dropdown for Foreignkey

Tags: django, django-admin

Python 3.6 ; Django 2.2

In the django-admin add or change object forms we have dropdown fields for ForeignKeys;
This is well, but when you try to search an input from this dropdown we have to press keys very fast to not loose previous input;

For example having:

```
class PC:
    .....
    location = models.ForeignKey('Locations', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

we get in add/change form:
[image]

where for search in this dropdown is needed to type fast '1-9-07', (if not fast you will get search from beginning for each character)

So the question is:

There is any way in django-admin to get this search delay more than 1 second for example to set it for 5 seconds interval between any input?

Or to get something like this:[image]

So the search input will not be reset, until you not reset it manually.

(this example is not from django)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Admin: change select box for foreign key to search autocomplete, like search objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544735/django-admin-change-select-box-for-foreign-key-to-search-autocomplete-like-sea)

Answer (score 1):

From django 2.0, there is already implemented feature;
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields

So in admin.py:

```
class PCAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    autocomplete_fields = ['location']

class locationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    ordering = ['name']
    search_fields = ['name']
```